# How to represent global state as a cartesian product of multiple variables?

Tags: uml, state-machine

I'm using a finite state machine to represent the lifetime of a desktop application, specifically what changes the desktop application has to do when some states change.  I'm referring to stuff like the application going online/offline, the mainwindow being minimized/visible/full-screen, the window being active/inactive, etc.  Representing each state individually leads to a [combinatorial explosion of states](https://statecharts.dev/state-machine-state-explosion.html) which renders any diagram untenable.

To circumvent potential combinatorial explosions of states, I've looked into parallel states, but I found little to no references on how to represent them.  Also, my usecase includes specific application states that are triggered only in specific combination of states (i.e., full-screen mode when the app is offline needs to show an icon).

Is there any simple and manageable way to represent cartesian products of global states with minimum noise in a way that also includes state transitions when a particular combination of states happen?

Comment: I just would guess there is no silver bullet for it and you have to model each SM manually.

Comment: Also, for a UI the state machine should not be so complex that a human does not get it. It's probably better to apply business rules since the user needs appropriate feedback. So instead of the SM yelling "not possible in this context" the user will need some explanation for not being able to do what he wants. SMs are neat but once they get complex they are pure nightmares. So i try to tame them and keep them small.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is separation of concerns.

If you mix up very different concerns (e.g. online/offline with the backend and visible/minimized, maximized for the UI), in a state machine, you might not only end up with a multiplication of states (e.g. online/minimized, offline/minimized, etc) but a very complex transition scheme.

Fortunately, you can keep concerns separated with the help of [composite state](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/compositestate.html) made up of nested orthogonal state machines.  One orthogonal region would model the online/offline lifecycle. Another orthogonal  region would be about visible/maximized/minimized.  Each substate would have only simple, relevant transitions.

The principle is that at any given time, each orthogonal region has one active state, e.g `Online` and `Maximized` are active at the same time, each having independent state transitions, until a transition of the enclosing composite state is fired.

Comment: "If you mix up very different concerns (...) you might not only end up with a multiplication of states (...) but a very complex transition scheme."  This remark doesn't make sense. No states are being multiplied because they already exist.  The challenge is representing them concisely.  The same goes for transition schemes.  Those transitions are already happening.  The problem is how to represent them in a simple way.

Comment: @RAM If you have 3 orthogonal state machines, with respectively 2, 3 and 4 states, so 9 states in total, and want to represent them in a single state machine without composite states, you’ll end up with 24 states

Comment: One transition in one orthogonal state of the first machine will result in 12 transitions with the states resulting from the cartesian products. So we are indeed speaking of the same transition but depending hiw you model you will end up with 1 or 12 transitions (resulting from combinatorial explosion)

Comment: again, the states already exist. Also, if you read the question you'll notice that the states aren't orthogonal, and some transitions are triggered only specific combination of states. Nevertheless, these things are irrelevant, given the question is on how to represent the states and transitions that already exist in a concise way without succumbing to combinatorial explosions.

Comment: @RAM what you call parallel state are orthogonal states in a composite state (see link in my answer). If you have a specific transition that you cannot convert using orthogonal states, please show the concrete example. Answering for the general case would probably require dozen of pages to cover all possible cases.